# Getting an error "file not found"

Tags: ieeetran

I am completely new to Latex. I have been trying to create a paper based upon `IEEEtran`. But when i tried to see the output after writing just 4 lines, i got an error "**file not found**".

I have already followed a [tutorial](https://softwareexperiments.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/installing-ieeetrans-and-the-ieee-bibtex-style-for-latex-in-ubuntu/) to use the IEEEtran

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{My IEEE paper}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This most likely means that your document is empty. In fact, the document `.log` probably doesn't show an error, but only that `0 pages were output`. Add `\maketitle` after `\title`, and/or add some content... anything.

Comment: The complete error message would most likely show, which file is missing. Do you have the class installed?

Comment: @Werner: Thanks, the error went when i add few more lines.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a compilation error that results from trying to compile a document with no content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You technically don't have any document content to typeset, since `\title{<stuff>}` only stores `<stuff>` as the title for when you use `\maketitle`. In fact, the document `.log` shows at the:

```
No pages of output.
```

And, since no pages were output, the document viewer opening up the output (as part of your workflow) can't find the file causing the error. Add more content to your document in order to follow your progress. Some like

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\title{My IEEE paper}
\begin{document}
\maketitle% Create/set the title
\end{document}
```